# Mac OS X shortcut problem using firefox

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, shortcuts

I am using Mac OS X. I had a look at the [Mac OS X Firefox shortcut table.](http://www.scribd.com/doc/615/Keyboard-Shortcuts-for-Mac-OS-X-Firefox)

Command+H should open the browser history.
Now, i really wondered why our users explained that this shortcut minimizes the browser.
I checked this myself and on my mac it minimizes the browser.

**Shoudn't the browser history open?
Does anyone have a different behaviour here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac OS X,

- <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> does not *minimize* a window, it will *hide* it.
- <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> will *minimize* it.

These are general keyboard shortcuts, you can try them in all possible applications, from Finder to Terminal, even Chrome does it. Only few applications choose to override this behavior (I can't recall one from the top of my head).

The document that you've linked to is at least from 2008. Now, Firefox uses <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> for the History sidebar, according to the [official Firefox keyboard shortcut help](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard%20shortcuts).

More generally, it is always worth checking the official help pages, as many keyboard shortcut tables found online can be outdated.